# Attempt to set a non-property-list object only on iOS 7.1.1

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

Everything is OK but it's NOT on **iOS 7.1.1**

I don't know why. My objects I try to save are `NSString` or `NSNumber` (I checked each objects)

Someone help me please!

```
Attempt to set a non-property-list object (
        {
        channel = "No Channel";
        channelId = "";
    },
        {
        backgroundColor = 5082e5;
        channel = Animals;
        channelId = 17;
        created = "2014-02-12T01:16:06.000000";
        exploreIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Animals_trans@2x.png";
        exploreName = Animals;
        exploreRetinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Animals_trans@2x.png";
        exploreStyle = icon;
        featuredChannelId = 337;
        fontColor = ffffff;
        iconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Animals.png";
        priority = 1;
        retinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Animals@2x.png";
    },
        {
        backgroundColor = be5fb6;
        channel = Art;
        channelId = 2;
        created = "2013-06-28T16:46:54.000000";
        exploreIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Art_trans@2x.png";
        exploreName = Art;
        exploreRetinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Art_trans@2x.png";
        exploreStyle = icon;
        featuredChannelId = 2;
        fontColor = ffffff;
        iconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Art.png";
        priority = 2;
        retinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Art@2x.png";
    },
        {
        backgroundColor = ff5867;
        channel = Comedy;
        channelId = 1;
        created = "2013-06-28T16:46:54.000000";
        exploreIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Comedy_trans@2x.png";
        exploreName = Comedy;
        exploreRetinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Comedy_trans@2x.png";
        exploreStyle = icon;
        featuredChannelId = 1;
        fontColor = ffffff;
        iconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Comedy.png";
        priority = 3;
        retinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Comedy@2x.png";
    },
        {
        backgroundColor = 33ccbe;
        channel = DIY;
        channelId = 1070175184667013120;
        created = "2014-04-21T23:44:20.000000";
        exploreIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/DIY_trans@2x.png";
        exploreName = DIY;
        exploreRetinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/DIY_trans@2x.png";
        exploreStyle = "<null>";
        featuredChannelId = 1070189388014780416;
        fontColor = ffffff;
        iconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/DIY.png";
        priority = 6;
        retinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/DIY@2x.png";
    },
        {
        backgroundColor = 68bf60;
        channel = Family;
        channelId = 7;
        created = "2013-06-28T16:46:54.000000";
        exploreIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Family_trans@2x.png";
        exploreName = Family;
        exploreRetinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Family_trans@2x.png";
        exploreStyle = icon;
        featuredChannelId = 7;
        fontColor = ffffff;
        iconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Family.png";
        priority = 7;
        retinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Family@2x.png";
    },
        {
        backgroundColor = ff794d;
        channel = Food;
        channelId = 10;
        created = "2013-06-28T16:46:54.000000";
        exploreIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Food_trans@2x.png";
        exploreName = Food;
        exploreRetinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Food_trans@2x.png";
        exploreStyle = icon;
        featuredChannelId = 10;
        fontColor = ffffff;
        iconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Food.png";
        priority = 9;
        retinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Food@2x.png";
    },
        {
        backgroundColor = 6caff1;
        channel = "Music & Dance";
        channelId = 11;
        created = "2013-06-28T16:46:54.000000";
        exploreIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Music_trans@2x.png";
        exploreName = "Music & Dance";
        exploreRetinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Music_trans@2x.png";
        exploreStyle = icon;
        featuredChannelId = 11;
        fontColor = ffffff;
        iconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Music.png";
        priority = 10;
        retinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Music@2x.png";
    },
        {
        backgroundColor = cccc52;
        channel = News;
        channelId = 14;
        created = "2013-06-28T16:46:54.000000";
        exploreIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/News_trans@2x.png";
        exploreName = News;
        exploreRetinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/News_trans@2x.png";
        exploreStyle = icon;
        featuredChannelId = 14;
        fontColor = ffffff;
        iconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/News.png";
        priority = 11;
        retinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/News@2x.png";
    },
        {
        backgroundColor = 7870cc;
        channel = Places;
        channelId = 5;
        created = "2013-06-28T16:46:54.000000";
        exploreIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Places_trans@2x.png";
        exploreName = Places;
        exploreRetinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Places_trans@2x.png";
        exploreStyle = icon;
        featuredChannelId = 5;
        fontColor = ffffff;
        iconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Places.png";
        priority = 14;
        retinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Places@2x.png";
    },
        {
        backgroundColor = f279ac;
        channel = "Science & Tech";
        channelId = 1070175340166619136;
        created = "2014-04-21T23:44:57.000000";
        exploreIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Science_trans@2x.png";
        exploreName = "Science & Tech";
        exploreRetinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Science_trans@2x.png";
        exploreStyle = "<null>";
        featuredChannelId = 1070188045032366080;
        fontColor = ffffff;
        iconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Science.png";
        priority = 15;
        retinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Science@2x.png";
    },
        {
        backgroundColor = 548899;
        channel = Sports;
        channelId = 9;
        created = "2013-06-28T16:46:54.000000";
        exploreIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Sports_trans@2x.png";
        exploreName = Sports;
        exploreRetinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Sports_trans@2x.png";
        exploreStyle = icon;
        featuredChannelId = 9;
        fontColor = ffffff;
        iconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Sports.png";
        priority = 16;
        retinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Sports@2x.png";
    },
        {
        backgroundColor = ffaf40;
        channel = Style;
        channelId = 12;
        created = "2013-06-28T16:46:54.000000";
        exploreIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Fashion_trans@2x.png";
        exploreName = Style;
        exploreRetinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Fashion_trans@2x.png";
        exploreStyle = icon;
        featuredChannelId = 12;
        fontColor = ffffff;
        iconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Fashion.png";
        priority = 17;
        retinaIconUrl = "/static/images/channels_v2/Fashion@2x.png";
    }
) as an NSUserDefaults value for key kChannelList
```

**=========================================**

**DONE**

OK, I found what caused this error. In the object I try to save into `NSUserDefault`, there are some **`NSNull`** object. (you can search with keyword "NSNull" in my post)

Under iOS 7.1.1, iOS just showed a warning message but on iOS 7.1.1, **APP WILL CRASH**

**SOLUTION**

Remove all keys with NSNull values. I'm using AFNetworking, so I wrote:

```
+ (AFJSONResponseSerializer *)afJsonResponseserializer {
    AFJSONResponseSerializer *ret = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    ret.removesKeysWithNullValues = YES;
    return ret;
}
```

And use it everywhere I need to parson JSon

Answer (score 0):

Try to add only a part of this code at the time. You should be able to narrow it down to the line giving the error.

With this in mind, remember that property lists consist only of certain types of data: dictionaries, arrays, strings, numbers (integer and float), dates, binary data, and Boolean values. If for instance your `icon` is a UIImage, then it is not allowed to be added to a plist.

Comment: Thanks! I found solution!